# Android library dependency version conflicts

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I understand that adding 2 different versions of the support library can cause conflicts which is why I get an error when I add the 2 dependencies  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` and `compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"`. The thing I don't understand is that when I add the design library to the compile list, `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'` , the dependency version conflict resolves when I sync the gradle project.

[image: Dependency conflict without the 3rd support library]

[image: Dependency conflict resolves when I add a 3rd support library]

Shouldn't there still be a conflict between `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` and `compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"`?

Comment: please use same version for android support.. just don't add diff version